# How to wait for a useState update within onSubmit?

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management

I want to fetch metadata from a website, then upload it to the database.
The website link comes from a form input field.

Since useState update is async, the data is not yet present in the formData object on submit.

What options do I have?

npm package in use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/suq

```
const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
const [url, setUrl] = useState("");
const [imgUrl, setImgUrl] = useState("");
   
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
     suq(
      `${urlToPost}`,
        function (err, json, body) {
        if (!err) {
          setTitle(json.opengraph["og:title"]);
          setUrl(json.opengraph["og:url"])
          setImgUrl(json.opengraph["og:image"]);
        }
      }
    );
    
    const postData = {
      title,
      url,
      imgUrl
    };
    
    db.collection("posts")
      .doc()
      .set(postData)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Document successfully written!");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
      });
}
```

Comment: state variables exist outside of `handleSubmit` function - you don't need to put `useEffect` inside it. Just do `useEffect(() => console.log({ title, url, imgUrl}), [title, url, imgUrl])` outside of `handleSubmit`.

Comment: While your statement is true, I figured this wil not do, because it runs at the initial render as well and the console log substitutes a database upload in this example. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this:

```
const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
const [url, setUrl] = useState("");
const [imgUrl, setImgUrl] = useState("");
   
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    let submitTitle = '';
    let submitUrl = '';
    let submitImgUrl = '';

     suq(
      "https://www.space.com/first-structures-in-universe-revealed",
        function (err, json, body) {
        if (!err) {
          submitTitle = json.opengraph["og:title"];
          submitUrl = json.opengraph["og:url"];
          submitImgUrl = json.opengraph["og:image"];

          setTitle(submitTitle);
          setUrl(submitUrl)
          setImgUrl(submitImgUrl);
        }
      }
    );
    
    const formData = {
      title: submitTitle,
      url: submitUrl,
      imgUrl: submitImgUrl
    };
    
    console.log(formData);
    // title, url and imgUrl are still at initial value

}
```

the local state updates will be available in the next render but the values you need will be available to you in your handle submit function

Comment: Yeah, this would work I guess. I was trying to apply a more react-y way with states. If there is no way to do it like that, I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Creating the formData outside the function didn't work for some reason. I might be lazy not to debug that... creating it inside the suq callback yielded the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

We can't handle the wait for the state update directly in the same call.

As the state will update its value after the re-render cycle.

So it's upon you what would you like to do with the updated state so I can help you.